# How to hide / disable tab bar item in swift

Tags: swift2, uitabbaritem

I have a five tab, tab bar controller in my app, and I want to only show the 5th item if a manager is logged into the app (instead of employee).

I currently have this code which disables the 5th item but I can still see it (its just grayed out and is not clickable).

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![4].enabled = false
```

Is there a way to only show the first four items and evenly space them if a non manager is logged in?

Comment: have you tried removing the item at index 4 ?

Comment: Thanks Leo! I was able to find an example where they removed it.  Half of my problem was finding the correct word to search for.  I kept searching for "hide" and "disable" but the correct word was "remove".

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
    let indexToRemove = 3
    if indexToRemove < tabBarController.viewControllers!.count {
        var viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
        viewControllers?.remove(at: indexToRemove)
        tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
}
```